# How to access Financial Items through API?

Tags: api, developer

In my organization, we have local chapters who sometimes get part of the national membership dues.  The BOD doesn't want the breakdown to show up on the email receipt, and the calculation has to be done whether the dues are posted online or offline, so I do my breakdown during the posting of the line item for the membership dues.

I access the chapter share and reduce the line item by the chapter's share and create a new line item for the chapters share, since it's a different financial type.  Everything works well, except the chapter's share doesn't show up on the bookkeeping report.  That's when I noticed that the Financial Item record isn't created for the chapter's share line item record.

So I looked at the API explorer and I can't figure out which API entity and which API call creates the Financial Item records.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think their is a separate API for creating Financial Item records - this gets created whenever an contribution and line_item is been created

so, you can write an API for creating financial_item also make sure you make an entry in entity_financial_item

or you can create these records manual using CRM_Financial_BAO_FinancialItem::add() which will create new financial item

Answer (score 1):

Version 4.7.6 opens access through api for Financial Item as well as other Financial tables.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for Financial Items in this extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/financial-item-api